# Отступы между ссылками в textview

Tags: android, textview

Ссылки в `TextView` расположены слишком плотно, зачастую нажимая на разные ссылки попадаю на одну и ту же(экран маловат). Можно ли сделать отдельный маркер, по нажатии которого будет появляться список со всеми ссылками в `TextView`?

Comment: `\n` , spinner или recyclerView  - в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На языке Java:

```
textView.text = "foo bar http://bar.foo bar foo http://foo.bar"
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
        URLSpan spans[] = textView.getUrls(); //извлекаем ссылки
        for (URLSpan span : spans) {
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(span.getURL());
        }
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                String url = item.toString();
                startActivity (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял, что такое отдельный маркер, вот пример по нажатию на `TextView` появляется меню со списком ссылок

```
    val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview)
    textView.text = "foo bar http://bar.foo bar foo http://foo.bar"

    //Эта строчка выделяет ссылки
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL)

    val popupMenu = PopupMenu(context, textView)

    //Формируется список ссылок
    textView.urls.withIndex().forEach { (index, span) -> popupMenu.menu.add(0, index, 0, span.url) }

    //Вешается слушатель на меню, по нажатию на пункт открывает браузер
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        val url = textView.urls[it.itemId].url
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(intent)
        true
    }

    //Нужно для того, чтобы сделать ссылки ненажимаемыми
    textView.movementMethod = object: LinkMovementMethod(){
        override fun onTouchEvent(widget: TextView, buffer: Spannable, event: MotionEvent) = false
    }

    //По нажатию на TextView появляется меню
    textView.setOnClickListener { popupMenu.show() }
```

Comment: P.S. kotlin? я думаю уместнее будет пока на java показать данный пример

Comment: Согласен с iFr0z

Comment: По прогнозу Realm уже через год Kotlin обгонит Java по популярности среди Android разработчиков.

Comment: @katso да я сам уже перешел на kotlin - удобнее :) но это не значит, что все сразу перешли) это же тоже самое, если на руСтаке ответит на английском языке (вроде тоже популярном)