# Преобразовать код написанный на kotlin в java

Tags: java, kotlin

На вопрос [Отступы между ссылками в textview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733905/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-textview) получил хороший ответ, но на языке kotlin. Прошу знающих людей "перевести" на java.

```
        //Формируется список ссылок
        textView.urls.withIndex().forEach { (index, span) -> popupMenu.menu.add(0, index, 0, span.url) }

        //Вешается слушатель на меню, по нажатию на пункт открывает браузер
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            val url = textView.urls[it.itemId].url
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URLSpan spans[] = textView.getUrls();

PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
for (URLSpan span : spans) {
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(span.getURL());
        }
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                String url = item.toString();
                startActivity (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу перевести на русский:

- Получаете список ссылок из TextView
- Проходите его циклом, добавляя каждый как элемент в PopupMenu, индекс в списке используете как menuId
- Вешаете слушатель на меню, где по menuId получаете ссылку из списка и отправляете Intent на просмотр ссылки